# Issue to add dynamic value in Highcharts jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I am facing an issue to add the dynamic value in Highcharts Jquery. I have two arrays like name and value

name/categoryname - ["ZYG", "BLA", "GAS", "LBE", "LIM", "EMB", "NAU"]

value/basevalue - [483.7932253,601.125844,680.2910403,886.7269613,548.3400347,630.8979143,0]

face the issue in passing the base value in. I tried to pass the value in the array and string type. The issue is not solved yet.

I used the bar chart to display. The coding is here. Normally coding works fine. The issue faced when I use dynamic value.

```
     function displaychart(obj)
    {       
        var categoryname = [];
        $.each(obj['name'], function( key, value ) { 
           categoryname.push(value);
        });

        var ybasevalue = "[";
        $.each(obj['basevalue'], function( key, value ) { 
            ybasevalue += value + ",";
        });
        ybasevalue += "]";

        Highcharts.chart('container'+i, {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Protein Sequence'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: categoryname,
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Proteomics',
                        align: 'high'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        overflow: 'justify'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ''
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 180,
                    floating: true,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
                    shadow: true
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                  series:[
                  {
                     name: 'Protein',
                     data: ybasevalue
                  },          
                  ]

        }); 
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pass an array of Strings instead of an array of Numbers. Values inside single or double quotes are Strings in JavaScript.

So I use

```
 var ybasevalue = [];     
$.each(obj[i]['basevalue'], function( key, value ) { 
ybasevalue.push(parseInt(value)); });
```

Comment: So the issue is solved? If not, could you reproduce it in an online code editor like jsfiddle?